# PHP - Create An Array For Every Paragraph

Tags: php

I have HTML being output like such on index.php:

```
<p>Value 1, Value 2</p>
<p>Value 3, Value 4</p>
<p>Value 5, Value 6</p>
```

From an external page, I would like to read each paragraph tag and populate an array, like such:

```
array (size 3)

    array (size 2)

        "Title" => "Value 1"

        "Field" => "Value 2"

    array (size 2)

        "Title" => "Value 3"

        "Field" => "Value 4"

    array (size 2)

        "Title" => "Value 5"

        "Field" => "Value 6"
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Yes. It's quite possible.

Comment: Check out [`DOMDocument`](http://us2.php.net/domdocument) and [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  Technically, @MarcB has fully answered your question.

Comment: Can you please provide a suggestion on how I could do something like this?

Comment: Here's some (pseudo) code: `if(isLIVE){ $suggestion="Google"; }else{ echo "Try something"; }`

Comment: Google "HTML parser php"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/domdocument) and [`::getElementsByTagName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). Example:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
  <p>Value 1, Value 2</p>
  <p>Value 3, Value 4</p>
  <p>Value 5, Value 6</p>
HTML;

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$paragraphs = array();
foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
    $string = $paragraph->nodeValue;
    list($title, $field) = explode(', ', $string, 2);

    $paragraphs[] = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'field' => $field,
    );
}

var_dump($paragraphs);
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Value 1"
    ["field"]=>
    string(7) "Value 2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Value 3"
    ["field"]=>
    string(7) "Value 4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Value 5"
    ["field"]=>
    string(7) "Value 6"
  }
}
```

Comment: while your handing out freebies can i get a coffee

Comment: Good thing you're getting it here, we don't serve coffee at our "pub" @Dagon Just the "Irish" type. ;-)

Comment: @Dagon, I first pointed them towards the documentation since I think that's the only way to learn. Now if they can't comprehend documentation..maybe they can use an example + documentation to learn.  If OP just wants to take this and run, well then its their loss.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an HTML parser. The one I'm most familiar with is [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
$html=file_get_html("file.html");
$paragraphs=new array();
foreach($html->find("p") as $p){
    $text=$p->plaintext();
    $arr=explode(", ",$text);
    $newarr=array("Title"=>$arr[0], "Value"=>$arr[1]);
    array_push($paragraphs,$newarr);
}
```